# Kafka Message Keys with Composite Values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am working on a system that will produce kafka messages.  These messages will be organized into topics that more or less represent database tables.  Many of these tables have composite keys and this aspect of the design is out of my control.  The goal is to prepare these messages in a way that they can be easily consumed by common sink connectors, without a lot of manipulation.

I will be using the schema registry and avro format for all of the obvious advantages.  Having the entire "row" expressed as a record in the message value is fine for upsert operations, but I also need to support deletes.  From what I can tell, this means my message needs a key so I can have "tombstone" messages.  Also keep in mind that I want to avoid any sort of transforms unless absolutely necessary.

In a perfect world, the message key would be a "record" that included strongly-typed key-column values and the message value would have the other column values (both controlled by the schema registry).  However, it seems like a lot of the tooling around kafka expects message keys to be a single, primitive value.  This makes me wonder if I need to compute a key value where I concatenate my multiple key columns into a single string value and keep the individual columns in my message value.  Is this right or am I missing something?  What other options do I have?

Comment: Do you want to upsert records using JDBC sink connector?

Comment: The JDBC sink is one of many connectors I would like to support.  I'm not interested in forming my messages to a specific sink (that kind of defeats the decoupling I'm after).  Also, I'm interested in supporting upserts as well as deletes.

Comment: I think it’s better and cleaner to use key as struct (without concatenation). For example, JDBC sink connector is supporting such keys out of box for upserts. Other connectors should be checked, but you can use SMT to transform messages as you need. Generally, you need to produce messages unmodified as possible and do transformations on consumer side

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you know the relationship between the message key and partition assignment.

As per my understanding, there is nothing that stops you from using a complex type like STRUCT as a key with or without a key schema. Please refer to the [API](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html#ProducerRecord-java.lang.String-K-V-) here. If you are using an out of box connector that does not support complex type as key, then you may have to write your own Single Message Transformations (SMT) to move the key attributes into the value.

The approach that you mentioned - contacting columns to create the key and keeping the values of the same column in the value attribute would work in many cases if you don't want to write code. The only downside I could see is that your messages would be larger than required. If you don't need a partition assignment strategy or ordering requirement, then the message can have no key or a random key.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have tried publishing some messages with complex keys; my issue is that it seems like most connectors don't expect it (or can't use it).  I also cannot publish messages with a key because i will need to support deletes in the consuming systems (by publishing tombstone messages - the key to delete with a null value).  In many ways, my question is more about what existing connectors can use as opposed to what I can technically create.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to follow-up with an answer that solved my issue:

1. The strategy I mentioned of using a concatenated string, technically worked.  However, it certainly wasn't very elegant.
2. My original issue in using a structured key was that I wasn't using the correct converter for deserializing the key, which led to other errors.  Once I used the avro converter, I was able to get my multi-part key and use it effectively.
3. Both, when implemented appropriately allowed me to produce valid tombstone messages that could represent deletes.